# My SSD just disappeared

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd

I have a mac mini, with two ssd, both internal. They worked fine for over a year.

The secondary (not system) ssd has just disappeared. While I was copying a folder on it, a popup appeared, saying it was not properly ejected.

Not even disk utility can see it any longer, even after a reboot. It contained many important files, I really need help.

Any advice?

Comment: I hope you have a backup. In the meantime, check cables; try it in an external enclosure over USB; try it on another machine too.

Comment: No backup needed, it just contained my dropbox and google_drive folders. Now, extracting a disk from a mac mini can be a long and even dangerous operation. I'd rather try something else prior to open my mini..